# How to publish desktop app with download link in Windows Store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

[image]

Like this many desktop software have external link to their download pages in Windows Store. So we bought access to Windows Store and until Windows Store allows desktop applications (which will happen with Windows 10 I think) we want to have link to our download page. But we can't figure out how to publish download link only. Because it require package which require Metro project in Visual Studio I think? So are we need to create empty project in Visual Studio or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Windows Store onboarding for desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn322034(v=vs.85).aspx) for the official docs and step-by-step

As a basic summary, you'll need to create a [desktop dashboard account](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=263765) and [certify the app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/jj134964.aspx) by passing the desktop [Windows App Certification Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=309666) tests

You'll also need a Windows Store company account. This will let you log into the [Windows Store dashboard](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=320577) and submit the certified app for submission.

Add in the metadata (name, description, link, etc.) and submit!

Comment: It seems desktop apps are not allowed anymore. The first link you provide now redirects to a text saying: "Desktop application listings are not a part of the Windows 10 Dev Center and Windows 10 Store experiences. Existing Desktop application listings will not be discoverable in the Windows Store on Windows 10, but will remain available for Windows 8 and 8.1 users". I wonder why is this. I guess they want everybody to publish universal apps instead.

Comment: UWP -- the OS/2 of the 21st Century.